# Transfering values in groups from one h5py file to another

Tags: python, arrays, h5py

In assigning values to h5py groups in various ways, I found descriptions online of a syntax that I have tried to adapt for the purpose, but this has not worked so far, any help would be much appreciated. The two files that I want to transfer between have an identical group and subgroup structure.

This is the syntax structure that I have played around with:

```
import h5py 
f1 = h5py.File('file1.h5','a')
f2 = h5py.File('file2.h5','r')
f1['group1']['subgroup1'] = f2['group1']['subgroup1']  
f1['group2']['subgroup2'] = 1 
f1['group3']['subgroup3'] = array 
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

I tried to assign the values in ‘subgroup1’ of ‘file2’ to the identically named subgroup in ‘file1’, which is empty. Then I want to assign a scalar as the only value in ‘subgroup2’, and then assign the value of an array to ‘subgroup3’. What am I missing?

While the fix suggested by @Bryce works for the specific example I prevoided (thank you), the application I'm going for still is not working:

```
import h5py 
template = 'dump.h5'   #the template file in the same directory as the notebook
filename =  'dem1.h5'  #name of the file to be created
f1 = File_key_structure(filename,template) #creates an empty file filename with identical structure to a hardcoded template
ftemp = h5py.File(template,'r') 
Display_structure(template,'extras',1)  #lists the group keys of template as well as the subgroups of 'extras
Display_structure(filename,'extras',1)   #lists the group keys of filename as well as the subgroups of 'extras'
```

Which outputs the ‘template’ key structure in the first line, and the ‘filename’ structure in the second:

```
['dt', 'dump_cadence', 'extras', 'full_dump_cadence', 'gamma', 'header', 'is_full_dump', 'jcon', 'n_dump', 'n_step', 'prims', 't']
<HDF5 group "/extras" (4 members)>
['divB' 'fail' 'fixup' 'git_version']
['dt', 'dump_cadence', 'extras', 'full_dump_cadence', 'gamma', 'header', 'is_full_dump', 'jcon', 'n_dump', 'n_step', 'prims', 't']
<HDF5 group "/extras" (4 members)>
['divB' 'fail' 'fixup' 'git_version']
Out: <HDF5 group "/extras" (4 members)>
```

And I double checked all of the other groups as well, the specific errors I get for each of the types of assignments are:

```
f1 = h5py.File(filename,'a')
f1['header']['prims'] = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])  #this works 
f1['extras']['fixup'] = ftemp['extras']['fixup']
f1['dt'] = 1
```

The last two assignments give the following error:

```
OSError: Unable to create link (name already exists)
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code with no problem with some random files I created, so I guess the problem is due to you are assigning values to files that are not exist.

So I modified your code to create `subgroup1` in `file1` if it doesn't exist, then assign the values to `subgroups`.

```
import h5py 
import numpy as np

f1 = h5py.File('file1.h5', 'a')
f2 = h5py.File('file2.h5', 'r')

if 'subgroup1' not in f1['group1']:
    f1['group1'].create_group('subgroup1')

f1['group1']['subgroup1'] = f2['group1']['subgroup1']
f1['group2']['subgroup2'] = 1 
f1['group3']['subgroup3'] = np.array([1, 2, 3])

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Thanks @Bryce that works, except for assigning scalars where I get: 'OS error: unable to create link (name allready exists)'